# How can i refresh muleContext by refreshing ConfigurableApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, mule, applicationcontext

In this code, the Application Context is refreshed. How can I refresh the mule Context after that?

```
import org.springframwork.context.ApplicationContext 

    public class ReloadService implements ApplicationContextAware{
          private ApplicationContext context;

        public void reload(){
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).refresh();
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you start Mule programmatically?

Comment: By refresh are you trying hot deployment or adding new endpoints at runtime?

Comment: @Pratik Shelar by refresh i try to load with new configurations

Comment: @Fariba how do you start Mule? Programmatically from your own code? Or do you use Mule Standalone?

Comment: @David Dossot Application running on mule-enterprise-3.4.0 and Spring 3. we have many parameters placed in .properties files managed by the spring context (Spring 3.1) using this line:

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:my-config.properties" />
to load new properties i use ConfigurableApplicationContext # refresh

Comment: Since you're running on Standalone, then hot redeploy your Mule application. That will reload the new configurations.